# Is there a more efficient way to implement limitTo in AngularJS based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set up rows with ng-repeats in them that are limited base don the screen size. I have all the break points set up, and I think in theory I have an idea of how to do this, but my first attempt does not seem to be working. Here's what I'm trying

In the controller I have this to check screen size -

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
    var sizeCheck = window.innerWidth
        $scope.$apply(function(sizeCheck){
            if(sizeCheck >= 2250){
                $scope.sizeControl = 6;
            }else if(sizeCheck < 2250 && sizeCheck >= 1800){
                $scope.sizeControl = 5;
            }else if(sizeCheck < 1800 && sizeCheck >= 1600){
                $scope.sizeControl = 4;
            }else if(sizeCheck < 1600 && sizeCheck >= 1260){
                $scope.sizeControl = 3;
            }else if(sizeCheck < 1260 && sizeCheck >= 600){
                $scope.sizeControl = 2;
            }else if(sizeCheck < 600){
                $scope.sizeControl = 1;
            }
        });
    });
```

So in the template I just have :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in marketItemsTest | filter:searchPrivate | limitTo: sizeControl"
```

In the top of the controller I have this to check the initial size :

```
    var sizeCheck2 = window.innerWidth
    if(sizeCheck2 >= 2250){
        $scope.sizeControl = 6;
    }else if(sizeCheck2 < 2250 && sizeCheck >= 1800){
        $scope.sizeControl = 5;
    }else if(sizeCheck2 < 1800 && sizeCheck >= 1600){
        $scope.sizeControl = 4;
    }else if(sizeCheck2 < 1600 && sizeCheck >= 1260){
        $scope.sizeControl = 3;
    }else if(sizeCheck2 < 1260 && sizeCheck >= 600){
        $scope.sizeControl = 2;
    }else if(sizeCheck2 < 600){
        $scope.sizeControl = 1;
    }
```

This works ok, but I'm wondering if there a more efficient way in javascript, or angular in general. This function fires every single time the window shifts, and runs all these checks, so I'm thinking there must be a better way to do this.

Would appreciate any input! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse [ng-matchmedia](https://github.com/AnalogJ/matchmedia-ng) module, using which your code would look like

```
if(matchmedia.isTablet()){
    $scope.sizeControl = 6;
}else if(matchmedia.isDesktop()){
    $scope.sizeControl = 10;
}else .....
```

and if you want to make it more efficient, do change only when the size changes rather than on each pixel change, you can use [angular-breakpoint](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularjs-breakpoint) which does broadcast an event on size change, you can combine it with the above module and then

```
$scope.$on('breakpointChange', function(event, breakpoint, oldClass) 
{ 
    if(matchmedia.isTablet()){
        $scope.sizeControl = 6;
    }else if(matchmedia.isDesktop()){
        $scope.sizeControl = 10;
    }else .....
});
```

I havent tried to combine those two ng-modules.

Comment: did the answer helped?